# How can I prevent Pop up from zooming in on Mobile?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, authentication, wordpress-theming

I am using a WP-template and the log in screen is a pop-up which doesn't show on mobile, or is very zoomed in. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your style.css file

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
#thim-popup-login-wrapper .thim-popup-login-container {
        height: auto!important;
}
```

Comment: Wow that was way easier than expected haha. Thanks so much!